# How to fix WebStorm Vue no warning wrong type props?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, webstorm

- WebStorm Build #WS-233.14015.89, built on January 23, 2024
- Settings - Vue Language Server (Volar)
- TS version 5.1.6

I use `<script lang="ts">`

Example props

```
name: {
  type: String as PropType<string>,
  default() { return 'text'}
}
```

Use props and no warning about wrong type in the IDE:

```
<AnotherComponent :name="100">
```

I tried changing settings, it didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.